# Images to be seen at the same size across all screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing a trying to show an object at its actual size on computer screens, I am having some trouble resizing the image to different screen resolutions and sizes.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Update your question with some codes which might help in answering it.

Anyway, try giving a fix width or height through css which remains same in all browsers and viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of pixels rather than percentages. This would definitely help you.
If you are still confused, please share your logic and coding attempts, so that everyone can help you in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have anything particularly interesting to share, I have the images at the right size in pixels but I am worried that the images will appear smaller on displays with a higher pixel density like a retina screen. I've been searching around but can't work out if this will happen.

Comment: Make sense now ! Try using [window.size](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml) . This will give you size of the screen in pixels. Once you get this number, you can adjust the size of your image to your intended one. To do so, you might require to make you of percentage of the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want image to be of same size, you should use a container div and put that image inside the container and then give a height and width to this container div.

It will be better if you can also give a max-width and max-height parameters to that container div in your css.

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

and your css

```
.container{
background:url('path/to/your/image');
width:100px;
height:100px;
max-width:100px;
max-height:100px;
background-size:cover;
}
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/u6zg58cb/

I have also come across CSS3 'vh' and 'vw' units
vh := viewport height
vw := viewport width

I suggest you can use these insted of pixels

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would this be the same size visually on all screen resolutions? I thought that using pixels would mean that the image would be smaller on displays with I higher pixel density. I am looking for say a cm to be exactly a cm in real life on all screens.

Comment: @Seamus You can use any unit you like, for example, a DPI (dots per inches) is a better alternative to pixels.